# Cassandra read latency high even with row caching, why?

Tags: performance, cassandra

I am testing cassandra performance with a simple model.

```
CREATE TABLE "NoCache" (
  key ascii,
  column1 ascii,
  value ascii,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='ALL' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

I am fetching 100 columns of a row key using pycassa, get/xget function (). but getting read latency about 15ms in the server.

```
colums=COL_FAM.get(row_key, column_count=100)
```

nodetool cfstats

```
            Column Family: NoCache
            SSTable count: 1
            Space used (live): 103756053
            Space used (total): 103756053
            Number of Keys (estimate): 128
            Memtable Columns Count: 0
            Memtable Data Size: 0
            Memtable Switch Count: 0
            Read Count: 20
            Read Latency: 15.717 ms.
            Write Count: 0
            Write Latency: NaN ms.
            Pending Tasks: 0
            Bloom Filter False Positives: 0
            Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom Filter Space Used: 976
            Compacted row minimum size: 4769
            Compacted row maximum size: 557074610
            Compacted row mean size: 87979499
```

Latency of this type is amazing! When **nodetool info** shows that read hits directly in the row cache.

```
Row Cache        : size 4834713 (bytes), capacity 67108864 (bytes), 35 hits, 38 requests, 1.000 recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
```

Can anyone tell me why is cassandra taking so much time while reading from row cache?

Comment: Is it actually hitting the row cache?  Does 'nodetool info' show number of hits increasing?  What did you set row_cache_size_in_mb to in cassandra.yaml?  The default is 0 i.e. row cache disabled.

Comment: row_cache_size_in_mb = 64

MAX_HEAP_SIZE = "2G"

Comment: nodetool info, output given and other configurations added in the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Enable tracing and see what it's doing. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2